# Jwplayer configuration setup fails with rtmp connection

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I have below response and using these fields I am setting up jwplayer. but it is not showing video stream and throwing below error.

> error loading stream, could not load server.

Below is iframe which loades url properly. but i want that url to be opened in jwplayer.

> ```
> <iframe class="embed-responsive-item"
>  src="https://stream.robertsstream.com/streamflash.php?stream=gulfstream_mbr&amp;referer=XpressBet&amp;t=1482322598&amp;h=f49a4561c2f23e3bed6b61960a6bd3cd&amp;usr=1486564&amp;optp=siteid%3Aqaxb%7Coriginid%3ADRF&amp;width=100%&amp;height=100%"></iframe>
> ```

And after loading iframe i get below response in the console.using this console response i am trying to get rtmp connection path and trying to open it with jwplayer.

```
 ConnectionManager::connect -> server array:
  rtmp://robertscc.fc.llnwd.net:1935/robertscc
  rtmp://robertscc.fc.llnwd.net:443/robertscc
  rtmp://robertscc.fc.llnwd.net:80/robertscc
  rtmpt://robertscc.fc.llnwd.net:1935/robertscc
  rtmpt://robertscc.fc.llnwd.net:80/robertscc
  rtmpt://robertscc.fc.llnwd.net:443/robertscc
 _authoInfo:
 response:
   result: success
   resultinfo: Success
   connectionpath: rtmp://robertscc.fc.llnwd.net/robertscc
   subscribe: true
   numstreams: 2
   streams: 
       s_gulfstream_fm_771 |   cust=XpressBet&type=live&user=1486564&ip=114.143.191.202&e=1482392553&optp=sitei d:qaxb|originid:DRF&h=756e42184c5cd0a1551e83286d370acb | 771
       s_gulfstream_fm_400 | cust=XpressBet&type=live&user=1486564&ip=114.143.191.202&e=1482392553&optp=siteid:qaxb|originid:DRF&h=d4b0855a025d4217b9d8db2aacaf1c2c | 400
  platform: SD
```

And using this response params i am setting jwplayer

```
 jwplayer("bigVideo").setup({
      'flashplayer': "/jwplayer/jwplayer.flash.swf",
      'autostart': 'false',
      'width': "100%",
      'height': "325",
      'provider': 'rtmp',
      'streamer': ['s_gulfstream_fm_771 | cust=XpressBet&type=live&user=1486564&ip=114.143.191.202&e=1482384563&optp=siteid:qaxb|originid:DRF&h=9ae0b89056478edcdb3218540662da2d | 771',
's_gulfstream_fm_400 | cust=XpressBet&type=live&user=1486564&ip=114.143.191.202&e=1482384563&optp=siteid:qaxb|originid:DRF&h=46addb82ea9af100df25423827282fea | 400'],
      'file': 'rtmp://robertscc.fc.llnwd.net/robertscc',
      'rtmp': {
        subscribe: true
      }
    });
```

How to open this live stream in jwplayer ? 
Am i giving streamer array in wrong way ?